# What is the difference between angular input and native html attributes on html tags

Tags: html, angular

For example on an input tag you can pass a maxlength in two ways

```
 <input [maxLength]="20" type="text">
 <input maxLength="20" type="text">
```

is there any practical difference to using one versus the other ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In angular when you want to add property value you can do it in a 2 ways.

**Without using []**

it will treat the value as string, for example:

`<input maxLength="20" type="text">` the 20 here is equal to `"20"` in javascript

**Using []**

It will return the javascript value of it, for example:

`<input [maxLength]="20" type="text">` the 20 here is equal to `20` in javascript NOT a string.

use brackets when dealing with objects, variables or javascript expression.

if you want to write a string as a value don't use brackets for example:

`<div class="container"></div>` if you wrote it with brackets you should explicitly converting the class name to string like `<div [class]="'container'"></div>`.

Answer (score 3):

an attribute in square brackets is used to bind a variable value

in compontent.ts

```
propertyMaxLength = 20;
```

in html

```
<input [maxLength]="propertyMaxLength" type="text">
```

Regards